# Hey Folks, I got a unexpected ¦¦ T_STRING over here, although the error itself seems pretty simple, i just cant figure out how to solve it

Tags: php, header

The unexpected ¦¦ T_STRING is on line 20. I already tried replacing empty with !isset, but the error stays the same. so its not empty whats causing it

```
if (empty($hp) ¦¦ empty($money)) { ( // Line 20
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever character "¦" is, that's not the one you need to be using. You need to use the pipe above your return key, such as "|"

```
if (empty($hp) || empty($money)){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                if (empty($hp) ¦¦ empty($money)){
```

The problem is the attempt at the [logical `or` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). It should be two unbroken bars `||`, whereas you have broken bars `¦¦`. This is treated as a constant name; then, when a constant with that name does not exist, it is converted to a string. Obviously in that context a string is not valid, hence the error.

You may have your keyboard settings configured incorrectly, or perhaps you need an unusual key combination (perhaps using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, depending on your particular keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

`if (empty($hp) ¦¦ empty($money)){` needs to be `if (empty($hp) || empty($money)){` ...conditional OR symbol is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "¦"  operator you can use

(empty($hp) || empty($money))

condition or 
`(empty($hp) OR  empty($money))`

'OR' operator